# Serialize on route creates extra instances of model in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I think I stumbled upon a bug in emberjs but before I point it out as a bug I'd like to know if I didn't do anything wrong in the first place. I have a list of artists (let's say the 'master'-view) and when a user clicks the "read more" link he/she gets to see the detail information about that particular artist. To make my urls more readable I'm working with a 'slug' (serialize).

This is how my router looks like:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('artists', function(){
    this.resource('artist', {path:':artist_id'});
  });
});
```

This is how my routes look like:

```
App.ArtistsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Artist.find();
  }
});

App.ArtistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  enter: function(){
    console.log("ENTER: Artistroute");
  },

  serialize: function(model, params) {
    return { artist_id: model.get('slug') };
  }
});
```

Now, the problem starts when the user clicks an artist name which then renders the detailed artist information in an outlet. For some reason the overview list gets updated with empty artist entries.

When I comment out the following lines, the problem disappears:

```
/*
  serialize: function(model, params) {
    return { artist_id: model.get('slug') };
  },
*/
```

Here's a screenshot what it looks like with the serialize hook implemented before and after the user clicks the 'read more' links:

[image: Before clicking]

[image: After clicking]

As you can see, suddenly there are two extra artist objects created and added to the overview list. Why is this happening?

Comment: I would need to see a jsFiddle or jsBin in order to be of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see, suddenly there are two extra artist objects created and added to the overview list. Why is this happening?

It is happening because ember does not (yet) support passing an alias to your model's `find()` method. If you load the same record by slug and id, you end up with two records stored in the Ember identity map. So when you load `/artists` and call `App.Artist.find()`, your api is returning a bunch of artists with ids like 1,2,3,etc. When user clicks on detail link, ember is calling `App.Artist.find(slug)` and saving the response with id=slug instead of the numeric id.

So as you pointed out, things work fine when you comment out the custom serializer, since without that in place you're only ever looking up artists by their numeric id.

One workaround for this issue you might consider changing your api to just use slugs instead of the numeric id. Then get rid of the custom serializer and things should *just work*. Another alternative  you can implement a custom model hook on `App.ArtistRoute`:

```
App.ArtistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var artists = App.Artist.find({ slug: params.artist_id });

    artists.one("didLoad", function() {
      artists.resolve(artists.get("firstObject"));
    });

    return artists;
  }

  serialize: function(model, params) {
    return { artist_id: model.get('slug') };
  }
});
```

See this blog post for a more detailed look at the issue: http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-find-a-model-by-any-attribute-in-ember-dot-js/

Comment: I tried your alternative solution but this keeps returning an assertion error: `Your server returned a hash with the key artist but you have no mapping for it`. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, this made me decide to change my backend to use slugs instead of numeric ids.

Comment: Cool. Not sure about the assertion error, sounds like the api is not returning the json in the format ember is expecting